# How to find out the total no of cell nodes configured as part of a rack in exadata?

Tags: oracle, exadata

I want to know the exact total no cell nodes configured as part of the rack by login into the first db node of Exadata machine and run some commands or check some files.

We are not able to believe the output of /opt/oracle.Support.Tools/onecommand/cell_group file or the cellip.ora files or ibnetdiscover cmd ,since in some customer environment those files outputs are not giving the exact no of cell node details.

So is there any other command or file to fetch the exact no of cell nodes as part of the rack on the first db node ,even in the case like customer added additional storage nodes as part of that rack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the answer.Connect the asm instance or any db which running on the exadata box and run the below query

```
SQL> select cell_path from v$cell;

CELL_PATH
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
192.160.10.5;192.160.10.6
192.160.10.7;192.160.10.8
192.160.10.9;192.160.10.10
192.160.10.11;192.160.10.12
192.160.10.13;192.160.10.14
192.160.10.15;192.160.10.16
192.160.10.17;192.160.10.18

7 rows selected.
```

So totally 7 cell nodes are there in this box.